# unable to cast COM object of type "system.__comObject" to interface type 'shell32.shell'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, shell32, shell32.dll

I run my project in win 7 and xp, but there is an error message, in this project I use shell32.shell to copy and extract automatic exe file,
does shell32.shell not work in windows 7 and xp?
if you can, please suggest that sheell32.shell can run

```
Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
Dim pathExeOnServer As String = "\\server\UpdateProgram\"

Try
                If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application"))) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application"))
                Else
                    'DO NOTHING
                End If

                Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                File.Copy(Path.Combine(pathExeOnServer, fileName & ".zip"), Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application", fileName & ".zip"), True)
                System.IO.File.Delete(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application\" & fileName & ".exe")
                Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application")
                Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace(Application.StartupPath() & "\RS_Application\" & fileName & ".zip")
                output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HchkA.jpg)

Comment: Is this a WinForms or console app? In which line the error thrown? As the first step, try adding `STAThreadAttribute` on the `Main` method in Program.vb if exists.

Comment: this is winform, initially i run this project in windows 10 and work fine, file copy and extract file running normally, when i try to run the exe file in windows 7 and xp, then it appears his error message

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception, it is not bombing in this code.  The constructor of the form bombed.  Always high odds that it is running on a worker thread, the VB.NET default instance feature is a very dangerous one.  Write Sub New, create the Shell object there, set a breakpoint on it.  Use the Debug > Windows > Threads window to verify that it runs on the main thread.  Do note that this went wrong a while ago, whatever form has the Update button is already running on the wrong thread.